# Command-line script PHP does not run

Tags: php, mysql, cron, lamp

I am trying to build a PHP script to process data manually to later convert it to a cronjob. This script also gets data from MySQL and a third-party [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) interface. When I try to run it from the command line I have an error and the script does not run.

It shows:

```
./test.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
Enter a number:
./test.php: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.php: line 5: `$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));'
```

Here's what I have in my script:

```
echo 'Enter a number: ';
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
var_dump($line);
```

I know this script works. What is wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You get this error because you execute this script like `./script.php`. In order to make sure the PHP script understand and run properly, you have to include `#!/usr/bin/php` at the top of your script.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'Enter a number:';
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
var_dump($line);
```

*If PHP is installed in the */usr/bin* folder. If not, you can verify using the `locate php` command and then use the right path.*

**Or** the other alternative will be

```
php /path/to/script.php
```